# Finding function with positive 2nd derivative but 'plateau' where 1st derivative increases slowly

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, curves

I am looking for a function that satisfies the following criteria:

$\ f(0) = 0$

$\ f'(0) = 0 $

$\ f'(x) > 0, 0 < x < 1$

$\ f''(x) > 0, 0 < x < 1$

$\ \lim_{x\to 1} f'(x) = \infty$

Additionally, I need:

$\ f'(0.01) \approx 0.24$

$\ f'(0.5) \approx 0.25$

$\ f'(0.98) \approx 0.26$

Basically, this means the derivative starts off at 0, quickly grows to around 1/4, increases slowly between 0.01 and 0.98, and then tends to $\infty$ between 0.98 and 1.

Currently, I achieve this with the following piecewise function:

$\  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
Ax^{2},  & \text{0 $\le$ x < 0.01} \\
B+ Cx + Dx^{2}, & \text{0.01 $\le$ x < 0.98 } \\
\frac{1}{1-x} + E + Fx, & \text{0.98 $\le$ x < 1 } \\
\end{cases} $

With appropriate values for A-F. However, I am trying to find a simple function with a continuous $2^{nd}$ derivative that also has all these properties. I am also looking to find cases where the derivative of the function has more than 1 'near plateau' (e.g. ranges where it is increasing slowly). For a function that satisfied the original 5 criteria above and:

$\ f'(0.01) \approx 0.24$

$\ f'(0.5) \approx 0.25$

$\ f'(0.6) \approx 0.5$

$\ f'(0.99) \approx 0.51$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the model
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D & x\in[0,0.01]\\
Ex^2+Fx+G & x\in(0.01,0.98)\\
H\frac1{1-x}+Ix+J & x\in[0.98,1]
\end{cases}
$$.
Then you have enough variables to satisfy
$$
f(0)=0\\
f'(0)=0\\
f'(0.01)=0.24\\
f'(0.98)=0.26
$$
You will get automatically $f'(0.5)\approx 0.25$ and $\lim_{x\nearrow 1}f'(x)=\infty$. But to make $f'$ differentiable you have to check
$$
\lim_{x\nearrow 0.01} f'(x)=\lim_{x\searrow 0.01}f'(x)\text{ and }
\lim_{x\nearrow 0.98} f'(x)=\lim_{x\searrow 0.98}f'(x).
$$
But this is possible in the model above.

**Edit:**

Consider
$$
f_n(x)=0.26\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}-\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)-(1-x)^{\frac1n}-\frac{x}n+1.
$$
Then we have $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Further
$$
f_n'(x)=0.26\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}}+\frac1{n}(1-x)^{-\frac1n}-\frac1n
$$
which yields $f_n'(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}f_n'(x)=\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n'(x)>0$ for all $0<x<1$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For $0<x<1$ we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}}=1\text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n(1-x)^{-\frac1n}-\frac1n=0.
$$
This yields $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x)=0.26$. Therefore you can choose $n$ large enough such that $f_n'(x)\approx 0.26$ for all $x\in[0.01,0.98]$.

Finally
$$
f_n''(x)=0.26\cdot\frac1{n(x^2+\frac1n)^{\frac32}}+\frac1{n^2}(1-x)^{-1-\frac1n}>0
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $0<x<1$.

If you choose $n$ sufficient large, you get all the properties you supposed. But unfortunately the convergence isn't very fast.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & f_n'(0.01) & f_n'(0.5) & f_n'(0.98)\\
\hline
10,000 & \approx 0.1838 & \approx 0.2599 & \approx 0.25999\\ 
\hline
20,000 & \approx 0.2123 & \approx 0.26 & \approx 0.26\\
\hline
30,000 & \approx 0.2252 & \approx 0.26 & \approx 0.26\\
\hline
40,000 & \approx 0.2326 & \approx 0.26 & \approx 0.26\\
\hline
50,000 & \approx 0.2373 & \approx 0.26 & \approx 0.26\\
\hline
60,000 & \approx 0.2407 & \approx 0.26 & \approx 0.26\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The function you are looking for could be $f_{50,000}$ or $f_{60,000}$.

Comment: For an economics paper. I was thinking of using the approach you suggested. However, I was wondering if there was a simpler, cleaner method.

Comment: What is a clean method? Do you think about a definition which is not piecewise? Than you could try $G_n(x):=\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1}+\frac1{n+1}$. It has the property $G_n(0)=0$ and $G_n(1)=1$ for all $n$. But for higher $n$ you get a plateau between $0.2$ and $0.8$. Since the value of the plateau decreases for increasing $n$, you have to scale it. This may be helpful for your construction.

Comment: A non-piecewise function would be very helpful. In your example, $G'_n(0) \ne 0$ and $G'_n(1) \ne \infty$, whilst for all n I tried  $G'_n(0.01)$ was still relatively far from  $G'_n(0.5)$

Comment: I edited my answer and gave an explicit and not piecewise definition of the function. I hope it is useful.